# global variable y0 conflicts with mathlib, cannot compile minimal C code

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

When compiling this code

```
#include <math.h>

double *y0;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

with `gcc 13.2.0` from latest debian-sid, I get the following error:

```
gcc -o a.out proof.c -Wall -lm
proof.c:3:9: error: 'y0' redeclared as different kind of symbol
    3 | double *y0;
      |         ^~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:490,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:27,
                 from proof.c:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:223:1: note: previous declaration of 'y0' with type 'double(double)'
  223 | __MATHCALL (y0,, (_Mdouble_));
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:6: proof] Error 1
```

Note that if I replace `*y0` with a different name, e.g. `*x0`, it does not complain.
Clearly there's a conflict of names with `mathlib`, but is this normal? should such kind of conflict be possible or is it a bug?

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0492/g/Chdjbggd

Comment: If you have a conflict you choose a different name. Life goes on.

Comment: @cipper: I wish I could upvote the question more than once for the laudable effort at producing a very short MCWE!

Comment: MCWE - MinimalCompilableWorkingExample (I believe), and I agree.  (+1)

Comment: This is why global variables should *always* be avoided.

Comment: "but is this normal?"

In a language that doesn't have any sort of namespacing, unfortunately yes.

Comment: @tadman In this case, [`y0` could be a macro](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/math.h.html#tag_13_26):  "The following shall be declared as functions and may also be defined as macros. Function prototypes shall be provided. ... `double y0(double)`".  Using `y0` on a POSIX install in any form risks UB.

Comment: The `y0` function isn't mentioned in ISO9899, forcing its presence is an easy source of trouble, given also a name that violates any contemporary coding standard. Note that you can define `NO_OLDNAMES` and still obtain a warning. Pretty insane.

Comment: @LuC  You also run into problems if you define a variable `int CreateFile;` on Windows systems, and `CreateFile` is not mentioned in ISO9899.  Is that also "[p]retty insane"?  Nevermind [`y0` being reserved by POSIX predates even C89](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/y0.html), as it was derived from [the Unix System V Interface Defintion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V_Interface_Definition), which is at least **40 years old or so**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle note that the usage of CreateFile is not due to a standard library in ISO9899, but from a Windows-specific one, there's quite a difference.

Comment: @LuC You seem to be unaware of [the **reason** ISO9899 even exists](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/rationale/a.html#1-1) (italics *original*):  "The Committee's overall goal was to develop a clear, consistent, and unambiguous Standard for the C programming language which codifies the common, existing definition of C and which promotes the portability of user programs across C language environments. 

The X3J11 charter clearly mandates the Committee to *codify common existing practice*."  The fact that some symbols were not included is **because some implementations lacked them**.

Comment: @LuC (cont)  C was **never** meant to be a limiting straight jacket. ISO9899 is a **least-common-denominator** standard that originated with the purpose of standardizing **common** practices, not **all** practices no matter how uncommon, and certainly **not** mandating limits nor the actual removal of **already-standardized** and commonly-used symbols such as `y0` and `j0`.  It would be utter craziness to expect the Unix world to remove symbols that likely date from the 1960s to satisfy some puerile 2020s "I want a pony!" complaint.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree with you: anything that's already an *accepted standard* has to stay. I was just exercising my right to a personal opinion: would you accept someone in your team choosing global identifiers as `y0` and `j0`? I would say it *insane*. The big bold word POSIX should turn it to *sanity*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y0` is the name of a [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) implemented in the math library. You should not use this name for a global variable.

Here is a list of the Bessel functions supported by most C math libraries, albeit not part of the C Standard as of C23:

```
// Bessel functions of the first kind
double j0(double);
double j1(double);
double jn(int, double);
// Bessel functions of the second kind
double y0(double);
double y1(double);
double yn(int, double);
```

These functions have been part of the POSIX Standard since the beginning, they have been available on Unix since [System V](https://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/vol1a.pdf) in 1983.  The GNU math library for C supports them by default, along with many other extensions, but as they are not part of Standard C, the declarations are conditional in `<math.h>` and omitted if strict standard conformance is requested with a compiler option (`-std=c89`, `-std=c99`, `-std=c11`, etc.).

Comment: They were in the Unix 7th Edition (circa 1978) maths library; there is a lot of precedent for their existence.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, some functions seem obvious candidates for inclusion in the C Standard, eg: `strdup()` that is finally added in C23.  But I am going to stop ranting until I work on becoming a member of the C Committee.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There's more than precedent.  [`y0` is explicitly a POSIX function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/math.h.html#tag_13_26).

Comment: POSIX post-dates 7th Edition Unix by a decade and more.  I don't know whether the Bessel functions were present before then; it's quite feasible that they were. And yes, they're in POSIX but not Standard C, mostly because they were in 7th Edition Unix and hence Sytem III and System V Unix, etc.

Comment: IMHO this is a widely accepted *pure madness*. A compiler that out of the box behaves strictly as POSIX is then incompatible with ISO 9899 - where are well defined all the reserved identifiers for standard libraries.

Comment: @LuC *A compiler that out of the box behaves strictly as POSIX is then incompatible with ISO 9899*  Please cite the portion(s) of the C standard - any version - that make reserving additional identifiers "incompatible with ISO 9899".  Given [**4. Conformance**, p6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p6), that's going to be hard to do.  4p6 reads, in part,  "A conforming implementation may have extensions (**including additional library functions**), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program."

Comment: @AndrewHenle may I have a *strictly conforming program* which has `y0` and `j0` as global variable? I would not do it myself, but I feel anyone should have the freedom for this foolish idea. That would be another matter if I were silly enough to declare a `sqrt` global variable.

Comment: @LuC `y0()` and `j0()` are commonly known mathematical functions in exactly the same way `sqrt()` is. Just  because you don't know that and don't know that Unix systems have a long history that predates the existence of standardized C of offering `y0()` and `j0()` via `math.h` that was standardized in [**1983**'s SVID](https://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/vol1a.pdf). Just because you're used to coding on systems that don't have that history doesn't make for a "foolish idea".  Foolish is expecting widely-used programming environments to not create standardized symbols 40 years ago.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I understand they're commonly known; the difference is that I can take another compiler, `#include <math.h>` and write an ISO standard compliant application that has a silly global `double y0;`. My argumentation is on the compiler choice. I would say that in another 40 years as well, but I'm quite sure I won't have that chance ;D

Comment: @LuC: These functions have been part of the POSIX Standard since the beginning, they have been available on Unix since System V in 1983. The GNU math library for C supports them by default, along with many extensions, but as they are not part of Standard C, the declarations are conditional in `<math.h>` and omitted if strict standard conformance is requested with a compiler option (`-std=c89`, `-std=c99`, `-std=c11`, etc.). An ISO Standard compliant application that has a silly global `double y0;` can be compiled now with gcc with the GNU libc/libm, and hopefully will in another 40 years.

Comment: @chqrlie ah-ha! I didn't try the code, but I hoped a switch enforced compatibility. However, I stand corrected about compilers: they're just tainted by pure evil. Tried a totally different approach in MSVC, and it's an even worse nightmare: they renamed `y0` to `_y0` but still don't accept `y0` as a new identifier, even with /std:c11 option ... another *insanity*

Answer (score 1):

`double y0( double )` [is a POSIX function with a prototype in `math.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/math.h.html#tag_13_26):

> The following shall be declared as functions and may also be defined
> as macros. Function prototypes shall be provided.
>
> ```
> double      acos(double);
> float       acosf(float);
>    .
>    .
>    .
> double      y0(double);
> double      y1(double);
> double      yn(int, double);
> ```

`y0` is therefore [a reserved identifier](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02):

> 1. Each identifier with external linkage described in the header section is reserved for use as an identifier with external linkage if
>    the header is included.
> 2. Each macro described in the header section is reserved for any use if the header is included.